# Prevent Ajax calls on Homepage

Tags: magento2, ajax, performance

What is the purpose of these ajax calls and how to prevent these Ajax calls on magento 2 homepage, or atleast minimize their execution time because they are taking load time of around 3-4 secs on my site.

> 1) banner/ajax/load/?sections=&_=1553687029673
>
> 2)
>   customer/section/load/?sections=cart&update_section_id=false&_=1553687029674

Comment: If you don't use customer/section/load/? request then login & logout link does not  work properly

Comment: ohh I see. So is their any way that their time could be minimized? It individually takes 2.2 secs of load time.